# Error in comparing a character output by BeautifulSoup vs a declared character

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract a character from a website and compare it do a character I have declared in the code.

In my case, I am looping through possible elements in the BeautifulSoup file look for a match to the letter Z when I call `.getText()`. Whenever I try and compare the characters I get this error message - SyntaxError: invalid syntax.

I'm also confused because when I declare them not in the for loop everything works fine.

Here is my code:

```
import requests, bs4
res = requests.get('https://www.example.com')

try:
    res.raise_for_status()
except Exception as exc:
    print('There was a problem: %s' % (exc))

noStarchSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)
ZElems = noStarchSoup.select('li')
TElems = noStarchSoup.select('a')

for x in range (0, 25):
    char1 = ZElems[x].getText()
    char2 = 'Z'
    if char1 == char2
        url = TElems[x].get('href')

print(url)
```

Here is the output I get:

```
if char1 == char2
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If I declare `char1` and `char2` outside of the for loop and have `char1` be at position 0 in the array, the comparison seems to work fine. Position 0 corresponds to `'A'`.

```
>>> import requests, bs4
>>>
>>> res = requests.get('https://www.example.com')
>>> noStarchSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)
>>> ZElems = noStarchSoup.select('li')
>>> TElems = noStarchSoup.select('a')

>>> char1 = ZElems[0].getText()
>>> char2 = 'A'

>>> char1 == char2
True
```

Is there something I'm missing about comparisons on characters in Python?

Comment: You need colon for if statement.  `if char1 == char2:`  This is python's rule.

Comment: @KotaMori Would there be a reason why nothing is being assigned to the url variable?

Comment: Python checks if the code is valid before running it.  Since there is a syntax error, it did not run.